# How to pass a variable from one method to another in the same class?

Tags: php, class, methods

Here's my code:

```
class something {
    public function one() {
        $choices = array(
            'something' = array(
                'name' => 'test';
            ),
            'something_two' = array(
                'name' => 'test_one';
            ),
        );
    }

    public function two() {
        ?>
        <select>
            <?php
            foreach ($this->function_one() as $choice) {
                echo '<option value="'.$choice['name'].'">'.$choice['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
```

The question is:
How to take a variable from another function and put it into foreach loop?

I am getting this error:

> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this, but I corrected all the errors I could see in your code, try this.

Your code did not have function one return anything. The foreach loop also calls the function differently, I've removed the workd 'function' and replaced it with `$this->one()`.

```
class something {

public function one(){
   $choices = array(
     'something' = array(
       'name' => 'test';
     ),
     'something_two' = array(
       'name' => 'test_one';
     ),
   );
   return $choices;
}

public function two(){
?>
<select>
  <?php
  foreach ($this->one() as $choice ){
    echo '<option value="'.$choice['name'].'">'.$choice['name'].'</option>';
  }
  ?>
</select>
<?php
}    

}
```

Comment: Oh, seems like i just forgot to return $choices. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of minor points:

- your array declaration had multiple syntax errors (`=` to `=>` and remove semicolons).
- when generating select options, you don't need to write the value attribute when it is the same as the text value.

I'll now offer a couple of working code blocks that use different techniques.

Code1: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xfo09))

```
class something {
    public function one() {
        $choices = array(
            'something' => array(
                'name' => 'test'
            ),
            'something_two' => array(
                'name' => 'test_one'
            )
        );
        return $choices;
    }

    public function two() {
        echo "<select>";
            echo "<option>" , implode("</option><option>", array_column($this->one(), 'name')) , "</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
}

$foo = new something();
$foo->two();
```

Code2: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OJjVQ))

```
class something {
    public $choices = array();
    public function __construct() {
        $this->choices = array(
            'something' => array(
                'name' => 'test'
            ),
            'something_two' => array(
                'name' => 'test_one'
            )
        );
    }

    public function two() {
        echo "<select>";
            echo "<option>" , implode("</option><option>", array_column($this->choices, 'name')) , "</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
}

$foo = new something();
$foo->two();
```

Whether you explicitly call `one()` from function `two()` or use a constructor to declare a variable (property) within the class (via object `$this`) will be dependent on your project requirements.  I'll avoid writing out a heap of quotes from the php manual; I'll just advise that you read some basic tutorials on classes and methods.